# Restarting ipyparall engines from within python

Tags: python, ipython

I wonder if it is possible to restart ipyparallel engines from within python.
I have the issues that a library I use has a memory leak (developers are informed) and quickly consumes all my RAM. When I stop the engines that RAM is freed.

But I need to run many iterations and my hack so far is to start the ipyparallel engines, run my program and stop the engines after the program ran in a looped bash script. But this way I have to read in a lot of data again. It takes several minutes. Therefore I wonder if I can restart the engines  in my python program.

Any idea is high appreciated!